FlexLayout размещение элементов
Мне надо сделать так чтобы SVG с надписью АМИРИ(title) была по центру nav (по вертикали и горизонтали) и SVG с тремя полосами(nav-menu) была само слева и по вертикали в центре.
Вопрос в том чтобы отделить элементы в сетке flex.
Что я хочу:
|||__AMIRI<3______0(:
HTML/CSS:


nav {
  height: 100px;
}

.flex-container {
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.title {
  justify-items: center;
}
<body>
  <header>
    <nav>
      <div class="flex-container">
        <div class="flex-element nav-menu">
          <img src="img/navmenu.svg">
        </div>
        <div class="flex-element title">
          <img src="img/title.svg">
        </div>
        <div class="flex-element liked>
                    <img src="img/liked.svg">
                </div>
                <div class="flex-element basket">
                    <img src="img/basket.svg">
                </div>
                <div class="flex-element profile element-right">
                    <img src="img/profile.svg">
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
</body>




как задать хороший вопрос

Возможно мне надо просто вытянуть их с одной сетки? И сделать по разным сеткам или просто отдельно?

Если ваша цель поставить title по центру, а остальные по разным сторонам, тогда думаю следует вынести вообще этот title из меню и абсолютом выставить по центру. А меню поделить на равные части вложения и с помощью justify-content: space-between расставить по разные стороны и сделать gap равный ширине title + небольшой отступ. А если не трогать html, тогда не знаю, может только скриптами, но тоже много вычислительных работ нужно делать. Например вырезать title и сразу же вставлять по середине меню + задавать ему уникальный класс, если вдруг он должен отображаться как-то по уникальному.

Насколько я понял это так можно сделать, но там вы должны ещё смотреть на реализацию заполнения через админку, если такая будет. Если будет, тогда нужно делать через один список и при этом title не будет входить в это меню. Я так понял title это логотип. Если честно не до конца понял, что вы там про вертикально написали.


.flex-container {
  min-height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  gap: 5px;
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
}

.nav-menu, .flex-element {
  width: calc(50% - 55px);
}
.flex-element {
  display: flex;
  gap: 5px;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
}
<nav>
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="nav-menu">
      <img src="img/navmenu.svg" alt="nav-menu">
    </div>
    <div class="title">
      <img src="img/title.svg" alt="title">
    </div>
    <div class="flex-element">
        <div class="liked">
            <img src="img/liked.svg">
        </div>
        <div class="basket">
            <img src="img/basket.svg">
        </div>
        <div class="profile element-right">
            <img src="img/profile.svg">
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>




Спасибо, очень сильно помог ваш ответ
